# Unable to resolve service for type 'WorkerServiceDocker.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'WorkerServiceDocker.Worker'.'

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, nlog

I am exploring the use of .NET Core to build a 'Worker' (what I would consider the modern implementation of a windows service, which is my background - .NET Framework / Windows Services). I am truly a beginner at IoC and DI.

I have created a .NET Core Worker, and have created an implementation of NLog writing to CloudWatch, with the code found below (in my Logger.cs class)

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void LogError(string message);
    void LogError(string message, Exception exception);
    void LogInformation(string message);
}

public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private static readonly NLog.Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public Logger(IConfiguration appSettings)
    {

        var awsTarget = new AWSTarget()
        {
            LogGroup = appSettings["Logging:TargetCloudWatchGroup"],
            Region = appSettings["App:AwsRegion"],
            Credentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials(
                appSettings["App:AwsAccessKey"],
                appSettings["App:AwsSecretKey"]),
            Layout = new SimpleLayout
            {
                Text = "${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${machinename} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
            }
        };

        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        config.AddTarget("aws", awsTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, awsTarget));
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
    }

    public void LogError(string message)
    {
        _logger.Error(message);
    }

    public void LogError(string message, Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.Error(exception, message);
    }

    public void LogInformation(string message)
    {
        _logger.Info(message);
    }
}
```

When I try to execute my worker in debug however, the startup fails with the following error:

[image]

I suspect this error is because I haven't registered ILogger/Logger as some kind of service etc using DI, into the CreateHostBuilder() section. However I'm unclear on how to actually register my Logger. There are a lot of options available and I'm unsure which will work (E.g. AddSingleton, AddLogging, AddHostedService and so on). I'm not having any luck trying these, so was hoping someone could assist if possible with how I actually inject my logger into the worker, and why to do it that specific way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `AddLogging` activates Microsoft-Extension-Logging (MEL). If you don't want to use MEL or any other fancy Microsoft stuff. Then you should register your `Logger`-object using `AddSingleton()` since you don't want multiple instances. But I would recommend you take a look at this ConsoleApp example that combines MEL with NLog: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/master/examples/NetCore2/ConsoleExample/Program.cs

Comment: You can also take a look at this HostBuilder-example that enables all bells and whistles from Microsoft and also integrates NLog with MEL. https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/master/examples/NetCore2/HostingExample/Program.cs

Comment: Thanks Rolf.. I may struggle to work out how to apply what's structured in the Console app to how my Worker service is structured as things look a bit different, in terms of Host Builder etc...but I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: I managed to get my logger added using services.AddSingleton<ILogger, Logger>(); but while the syntax is correct, I don't "understand" it. E.g. does this mean I have to register every Interface I add to my code in this manner? And why do I have to specify both the interface and the concrete implementation of that interface? Bit confusing. Any recommended reading on this topic? If I use a lot of interfaces, I'm imagining some massive list of services.Addxxxx in my startup?

Comment: For DI (services.AddSingleton etc) read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: @JamesMatson How to develop dotnet applications and make use of dependency injection sounds like a different Stackoverflow-question.